# Gathering dependency information took 6.36 min

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-injection, nuget, castle-windsor

I am trying to make my nuget package installations faster, but when I try installing, gathering the dependency information took like 6.26 min. I am using Castle.Windsor as my injector. My nuget server too, is a local server.

```
Gathering dependency information took 6.36 min
```

I would expect the installation to be much faster. i.e. resolving dependency should be made faster or by using a easier method.

Actually the 6.36 min is for gathering the dependencies, the nuget actions take below 30 sec.

Comment: First, please make sure the size of nuget packages that you are installing. If  the packages dependent a large size of dependencies, it will take a lot of time to download them. Then please install the packages with NuGet manager in Visual Studio directly to check whether this issue related to the Castle.Windsor injector or not. If possible, please tell us what packages do you install in your project?

Comment: Please also check your internet, make sure it could download the dependencies smoothly.

Comment: What is the version of you nuget package manager?  With older NuGet 2 the package sources were tried in order but with NuGet 3 and above they are tried in parallel so you cannot rely on the ordering. Besides, the experience is better in VS 2017 with package reference, you can check it with VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/), it will manage also the transative dependencies for you once you have correctly configured it and it is actually faster than the integrated NugetPackageManager.

In the other hand you can use [FAKE](https://fake.build/) so you will have the ability to produce your own nugets.

Both works pretty good together but both are quite hard to set up, but once you have it you can carry it to other projects.

I cannot provide you any code since it doesn't looks like it is a coding problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18186590)

Comment: It is not something trivial, it is impossible to explain both parts here, the one to convert to nugets, and the one to sustitute nugetpackage manager, that is why I just left the link, but you are right, I have to admit. But those were my reasons to not do it.